# Data from post request

Tags: jquery, post, global

```
var pload = function(ctrl, func){
    var dataa;
    $.post("/index.php/"+ctrl+"/"+func,{}, function(data){
    dataa = data;
    });
    return dataa;
};

var bind = function(hashtag, ctrl, func, div){
    $(document).on("click", "a[href="+hashtag+"]", function() {
            var body = pload(ctrl, func);
             alert(body);
            $(div).html(body);
    })
}
```

How I can get **data** in global? I want, so `pload` return **data** from post request. But I get "**undefined**" in `alert()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: This question was already asked a lot of times here in Stack Overflow. Take a look at the link above, it really will make you understand why it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using callback.

```
function pload(ctrl, func,callback){
    $.post("/index.php/"+ctrl+"/"+func,{}, function(data){
        callback(data);
    });
};

var bind = function(hashtag, ctrl, func, div){
    $(document).on("click", "a[href="+hashtag+"]", function() {
        pload(ctrl, func,function(body){
            alert(body);
            $(div).html(body);
        });             
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

tyr this:

```
var pload = function(ctrl, func){
    var dataa;
    $.post("/index.php/"+ctrl+"/"+func,{}, function(data){
    dataa = data;
    return dataa;
    });

};
```

Comment: Will that cause the function `pload` to return `dataa`?
I think it will cause the function that is called when the async call finishes to return `dataa` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting any value back because `$.post` is asynchronous, and won't halt the program until it receives a value back.

You should move the data handling portion to the function which will be called when the async call returns its result.

```
var pload = function(ctrl, func){
    var dataa;
    $.post("/index.php/"+ctrl+"/"+func,
      {}, 
      //this function will be called when $.post receives its response
      function(data){
        alert(data);
        $(div).html(data);
      });
    return dataa;
};
```