# cannot callback data from $.post

Tags: jquery

I'm cannot return data from $.post to function() 
pls help

refer url : [Data from post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018766/data-from-post-request)

```js
test = {
    
  getData : function (callback){
    
    $.post("getdata.php",{data: data},function(data){
      
          callback(data);
      }
           
    }

}
           
var data = test.getData(callback);     
           
console.log(data);
```

** TypeError : callback is not a function

thank you

Comment: what is `callback` used in `var data = test.getData(callback); `

Answer (score 0):

The `callback` like you think is not a keyword or default argument. It is the reference of the function to be executed after the AJAX call is performed. You haven't declared what's `callback`. You have to do something like:

```
function callback (data) {
  // do something with data
}
```

You can also define `callback` this way:

```
var callback = function (data) {
  // do something with data
}
```