# Handle data from $.post request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I wanna get and handle the data from a POST request.

I got the code:

```
function GetSqlResult (sql_query) {
  var result = [];
  $.post("getsqlresult.php", {
    sql: sql_query
  },
  function(data){
    result.push(data);
  });

  return result;
};
```

I get the error "result.append(data) is not a function".

I don't know if that what I'm doing is possible, but I wanna collect the data in an array.

This "could be" a duplicate from "[Data from post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018766/data-from-post-request)" , but it didn't work with the responses from that question, that's why I'm asking with my own code.

Comment: Javascript arrays do not have a function named `append`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array You want `result.push(data)`

Comment: oh shit, that's right, so sorry

Comment: That said, we should mention that `return result` will not do what you expect.

Comment: @DelightedD0D, thank you very much, this was the dumbest thing ever, I really thought the problem was handleling the post response

Comment: really?, How so?

Comment: No worries, Ajax is an asynchronous operation. ie, the call happens in the background and further code execution inline continues. That is to say, `GetSqlResult` will call `return result` and return your empty array *before* the ajax finishes

Comment: oh, so what should I do?

Comment: Instead of calling `result.append(data);`, make a new function called `handleResponse` and call `handleResponse(data);` then, do your stuff in that function :)

Comment: Beyond that little hiccup the whole approach is wrong since `$.post()` (which is a shortcut for `$.ajax()`) is **asynchronous**

Comment: You can even pass it in like `$.post("getsqlresult.php", {sql: sql_query}, handleResponse);`

Comment: Also a horrible security flaw if you are actually putting sql query strings in client side code where anyone can see them

Comment: @charlietfl , thank you, I didn't know that

Comment: @DelightedD0D, I'm gonna try, thanks

Comment: @MarianaLeites to charlietfl's comment, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection